# Android notifications generated NotificationCompact.Builder not working

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to generate notifications using `NotificationCompact.Builder` class as described here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html.

Below is my code

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String notification_type, String receiver_type) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My App")
            .setWhen(time)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setContentText(message);

    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent;
    resultIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);

    if(notification_type.equalsIgnoreCase("message")){
        if(receiver_type.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            resultIntent = new Intent(context, MyMessageForTutorActivity.class);
        else
            resultIntent = new Intent(context, MyMessageActivity.class);
    }       

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(QuickNotesActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

This works good on my **Samsung tab 2** that is **Android 4.1**, however when a notification comes on my **Samsung galaxy S** that is **Android 4.0**, it just displays error that **My-App-Name has crashed**. So the notification is being received through `GCM` but not being generated, instead my application crashes when a notification arrives. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: post the logcat details of the crash

Comment: Are you using the v4 support library?

Comment: Yes I am using v4 library. And @Raghunandhan, The app crashes when a push notification arrives. It doesn't show up on the logcat. Besides the issue was fixed by removing TaskStackBuilder. Not quite sure if it is compatible on API levels < 16 but I am using a v4 library so it should've been running.